# Android PhotoEditor send Bitmap in Intent

Tags: android, image, android-intent, bitmap

Good morning, I'm using this Github library: https://github.com/burhanrashid52/PhotoEditor as photo editor. I have a GalleryFragment in which user choose image from his gallery, the I pass correctly the image to the EditImageActivity where user can apply sticker, filters, ecc. and then clicking on a button, user can pass the edited image to InfoActivity, where he can add other info and publish the image.

The problem is that when user edits an image and pass it to InfoActivity it is shown the original image without changes, and also when he publishes it, the image saved is the original, not the modified.

I'm trying to use Bitmap to do that:

This is the code of EditImageActivity where I try to send the edited image in a intent to InfoActivity:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Bitmap bmp =((BitmapDrawable)mPhotoEditorView.getSource().getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                Intent intent = new Intent(EditImageActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("imm", byteArray);
                startActivity(intent);
```

And this is the piece of code of InfoActivity, where I try to retrieve the intent with the edited image from EditImageActivity, to show it in a ImageView:

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("imm");
        assert byteArray != null;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        immagine.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

So it works when user doesn't edit image, while when he edits image, it shows the original.

I think that the problem is in this code (the code that I use in EditImageActivity to get a bitmap of the edited image), because it passes the original image instead of the modified image:

```
                Bitmap bmp =((BitmapDrawable)mPhotoEditorView.getSource().getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: That last statement is in which activity?

Comment: EditImageActivity

Comment: No we cannot help you as it is unclear how you transfer   your image to or from an activity and then to yet an activity. Or how you thread a bitmap and send it back.

Comment: You better show in short how that editactivity receives the bitmap, edits it and sends it back.

Comment: I use the first piece of code that I posted to send it from EditImageActivity to InfoActivity (using bitmaparray in the intent), while the second piece of code is the code that I use in InfoActivity to retrieve the bitmaparray from the intent. Instead, the last code that I posted is the code (which is also in the first piece of code, in EditImageActivity) where I think there is the error

Comment: You should not give that info in comments as it keeps your post hard to understand. Put all info in your post at the right place.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I modified the main post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it seems that the problem is when you fetch the edited image from your PhotoEditorView.  If you see the documentation, to retrieve this image, is necessary to implement the next approach:

```
PhotoEditor.saveAsFile(filePath, new PhotoEditor.OnSaveListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onSuccess(@NonNull String imagePath) {
                    Log.e("PhotoEditor","Image Saved Successfully");
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                     Log.e("PhotoEditor","Failed to save Image");
                 }
             });
```

So the library needs a file to save it and if is success, then returns the path file, with the path file you needs to create the Bitmap object.

Comment: ok thank you very much, so I have to try to implement the bitmap intent inside the onSuccess, right?

Comment: yes, in the onSuccess you have the image path to retrieve later

Comment: Don't forget to compress the bitmap :D